# I have an error in retrieving data from database while using "AND" in "Case When"

Tags: mysql

I have an error in retrieving data from database while using "AND" in "Case When" 
I am trying to only retrieve data that have "Open" date that is greater than "current date +10 days" and the project status should be "Not closed", I used "and" in "Case when" but it still shows not closed and closed statuses.
Any help would be appreciate

```
SELECT
    Open,
    `TE Due Date`,
    `Certifier Due Date`,
    Close,
    ProjectStatus,
    case when ((DATE_ADD(Open, INTERVAL 10 DAY) > CURDATE()) and (ProjectStatus="Not Closed")) then "10 days passed from open date" else "" END AS "Open Status"
FROM 
    TCB
where DATE_ADD(Open, INTERVAL 10 DAY) > CURDATE() 
order by Open
```

Comment: write your case expression the same as your description, add 10 days to curdate, then compare to `open`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition and your description of your condition do not match up; you say you want *"have Open date that is greater than current date +10 days*, but `DATE_ADD(Open, INTERVAL 10 DAY) > CURDATE()` is "greater than current date MINUS 10 days".

Use `Open > DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 10 DAY)` instead; not only does it reflect your proposed condition, but it should also be faster as it operates on a value that does not vary by row (i.e. DATE_ADD should only be be calculated once for each query execution).

Edit: However, judging from *"10 days passed from open date"*, this is probably the actual condition you need `Open < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 10 DAY)`.

Your original condition actually means "opened in the last ten days".

Answer (score 0):

Put `ProjectStatus="Not Closed"` in the WHERE clause, not the select portion.

If you want to filter rows out, you do that in the WHERE.

If you want to do some logic on the values in an already selected row, that’s when you put a CASE WHEN in the select

```
—-shows all people and turns the isMale 0/1 into a readable word
SELECT name, CASE WHEN isMale = 1 THEN 'male' ELSE 'female' end 
FROM Person

—-shows only males
SELECT name 
FROM Person
WHERE isMale = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. As you only need to filter data, no need of case statement

```
SELECT
Open as “Open Status”
`TE Due Date`,
`Certifier Due Date`,
Close,
ProjectStatus
FROM 
TCB
where ProjectStatus= “Not Closed” and 
DATE_ADD(Open, INTERVAL 10 DAY) > CURDATE()
order by Open
```